# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.0.2.0

Tags: owin, katana

The searches I've run on this site and the internet in general address loading issues as an application issue. I have an assembly, System.Web.Http.Owin that, using IL Spy, I determined has a dependency on Microsoft.Owin 2.0.2.0, while the (latest stable) version of Microsoft.Owin pulled from NuGet is 3.1.0.0. All of the other assemblies referencing Microsoft.Owin are referencing v3.1.

I understand that System.Web.Http.Owin is pulled in as part of the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi package and the latest stable version of that is 5.2.3. How can I get it to reference the current version of Microsoft.Owin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my issue turned out to be simple: add an entry in app.config for the Microsoft.Owin dependent assembly

The compiler then loaded the package.